Does anybody know what this phrase means? (Oracle bones)
The phrase on the right, next to is theres some context.
From what I found it means x處化 but idk what the 1st one means.
Any help appreciated :)


The three characters together (henceforth: 【ＸＹ化】) probably make up the name of a high-ranking military officer serving King Wǔ Dīng of Shāng, as can be gathered from numerous fragments. For example:

《合集》5440 正

乙子（巳）卜，㱿鼎（貞）：【ＸＹ化】贊1王事
Divination on the day of yǐsì, Oracle 㱿 asked: Will 【ＸＹ化】 support1 the king's affairs?


《合集》6650 正

丙辰卜，古鼎：【ＸＹ化】受㞢（有）又（祐）？三（旬）又日戊（子）？⿽屮戈（翦）方。2
Divination on the day of bǐngchén, Oracle 古 asked: Will 【ＸＹ化】 receive divine protection? On a day of wùzǐ, 30 days later, 【】 is defeated.



The fragments in your image are filled with records of 【ＸＹ化】 attacking (翦) a tribe called 【⿱角廾】.

References:

蔡哲茂《釋殷卜辭的（籫）字》
馮時《古文字與古史新論》p. 228


the rightest three characters are recorded in 甲骨文合集 5439正，5440正


well, only the third one is recognised as “化”
the second one is treated as “冖” + “止”
the first one is not yet recognised (represented by t3, or t81) 

have fun :)

Thanks a lot! May I know whats that website(?) on the last pic?

@ginchan, it’s “先秦甲骨金文簡牘詞彙庫”, recommended by another user droooze  https://inscription.asdc.sinica.edu.tw/c_index.php
